# Sharepoint Lookup Column with Multiple Display Vertically

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, multiple-values

I'm using a SharePoint lookup column that has a multi-select choice field.

When 2 or more values are selected for an item, it is displayed in the view like this:

Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6

Is there a way that I can display this field as shown below?

Value1

Value2

Value3

Value4

Value5

Value6

Answer (score 1):

Try below JSON formatting on your multi-lookup column in list view to show data vertically:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "width": "100%"
      },

      "txtContent": "=join(@currentField.lookupValue, '\n')"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works pretty much perfectly. I had to adjust the width so that the string didn't just wrap at the edge of the column width. This still happens if your manually drag the width of the column, but it works.

Comment: Glad this works. Kindly try after removing width line from json. So you will not have to drag the column.

Comment: I've ran into a bit of an issue. When the width of each item is too short it still goes to one line. Is there anyway to explode the results and break them by the ; and then have them sorted like a regular HTML list?

Comment: List this... [Example](http://mickesotoole.com/images/list.JPG)